# How to handle the change selected item event of dynamically created DropDown List in PHP by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

```
function printDropDownList($lbId,$elements,$header)
             {
                 print "
                <tr><th align=\"right\">$lbId: </th><td>
                    <select id=\"$lbId\" style=\"width:80px;\" class=\"text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all\">";

                    foreach($elements as $item)
                    {
                        print "<option value=\"$item[0]\">$item[1]</option>";
                    }

                print "</select>";                         
             }

             $db = new Database();           

             $listHeaders = $db->arrayOfChildFacetsOneLevel(206);
             $i=0;
             foreach($listHeaders as $listHeader)
             {
                $facets = array();
                $q=0;
                $db->arrayOfChildFacetsRecursive($facets,$listHeader[0],$q);
                printDropDownList("list".$i,$facets,$listHeader);
                $i++;
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event for this

```
$("#yourdropdownid").live("change", function(){
    var selectedVal = this.value;
});
```

If you have more than element for which you need to bind the event then put a class name for those and you can use the class selector.

```
$("select.yourclassname").live("change", function(){
    var selectedVal - this.value;
});
```

Comment: And how can I get the ID/Value of the selected item?

Comment: Perfect! You might have missed the '' around change that's why it produced an error. The link showed everything as well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: change needs to be 'change' (in quoutes)

Comment: I will be creating many lists dynamically.
Is there a way to prevent writing the same event handler for every different ID? They'll all have the same action.